# Search substring in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6.5

Below is what I want-

Suppose in elastic search below are stored

1. Quick Fox Test
2. Quick Fox
3. Quick 123 @ Test
4. Quick
5. Fox Test
6. Fox Quick Test

Now when I search for

**Quick** then I must get

- Quick Fox Test
- Quick Fox
- Quick 123 @ Test
- Quick
- Fox Quick Test

**fox test** then I must get

- Quick Fox Test
- Fox Test

**Quick Test 123** then I must get

- Empty response

**123 @** then I must get

- Quick 123 @ Test

**123 $** then I must get

- Empty response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [match_phrase query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) to get the expected output and you need to use the [whitespace tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-tokenizer.html) with a [lowercase token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html) to make it work. will add the working example.

**Index mapping**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "lwhitespace": { 
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "message": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "lwhitespace"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index sample docs**

```
{
    "message" : "Quick Fox Test"
}

{
    "message" : "Quick Fox"
}

{
    "message" : "Quick 123@ Test"
}

{
    "message" : "Quick"
}

{
    "message" : "Fox Test"
}

{
    "message" : "Fox Quick Test"
}
```

**Search queries**

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
            "message": "Quick"
        }
    }
}
```

**Search result**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "66287786",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "4",
                "_score": 0.3147369,
                "_source": {
                    "message": "Quick"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "66287786",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.25613075,
                "_source": {
                    "message": "Quick Fox"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "66287786",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.21592417,
                "_source": {
                    "message": "Quick Fox Test"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "66287786",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 0.21592417,
                "_source": {
                    "message": "Quick 123@ Test"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "66287786",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "6",
                "_score": 0.21592417,
                "_source": {
                    "message": "Fox Quick Test"
                }
            }
        ]
```

**Search query `fox test`**

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
            "message": "fox test"
        }
    }
}
```

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "66287786",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "5",
                "_score": 0.93851364,
                "_source": {
                    "message": "Fox Test"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "66287786",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.79118896,
                "_source": {
                    "message": "Quick Fox Test"
                }
            }
        ]
```

**Search query for `123@`**

```
    "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
            "message": "123@"
        }
    }
}
```

**Search response**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "66287786",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 1.3792357,
                "_source": {
                    "message": "Quick 123@ Test"
                }
            }
        ]
```

**Search query for `Quick Test 123`**

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
            "message": "Quick Test 123"
        }
    }
}
```

And search result is empty

```
 "hits": []
```